# purescript data as array of all possible data inhabitants

Tags: types, purescript

I got the following data type:

```hs
data Icon = IconCircle | IconSquare | IconStar
```

I need an array of all possible `Icon`s?:

```hs
allPossible :: Array Icon
allPossible = [IconCircle, IconSquare, IconStar]
```

Is there a shortcut to create this array? e.g when there are 20 (or a lot more) possible Icons?

When not:

Is it possible to create a type for `allPossible` that forces all possible Icons to be included?

My goal is to force that this array is never incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is!

You can derive `Generic` and then use `GenericEnum` in combination with `GenericBottom` to enumerate all constructors:

```hs
data Icon = IconCircle | IconSquare | IconStar
derive instance Generic Icon _

allPossible :: Array Icon
allPossible = unfoldr (\a -> Tuple a <$> genericSucc a) genericBottom
```

And you can even make this completely generic, so it would work for any type, not just for `Icon`:

```hs
allPossible :: forall a rep. 
  Generic a rep =>
  GenericEnum rep => 
  GenericBottom rep => 
  Array a
allPossible = unfoldr (\a -> Tuple a <$> genericSucc a) genericBottom
```

Of course, this will only work for types that are actually enums - i.e. every constructor is either parameterless or its parameters have instances of `Enum`. If the type is not an enum in this sense, this will fail to compile, complaining that it's impossible to construct a `GenericEnum` instance.

Comment: Hint: these imports are necessary:
```
import Data.Functor ((<$>))
import Data.Tuple
import Data.Unfoldable (unfoldr)
import Data.Bounded.Generic (genericBottom)
import Data.Enum.Generic (genericSucc)
import Data.Generic.Rep (class Generic)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fyodor's answer is incorrect unfortunately. The last value is omitted because it is mapped on it's non existing successor (i.e. Nothing).

A working alternative might be:

```
allPossible :: Array Icon
allPossible = unfoldr (\b -> b >>= next) $ Just genericBottom
  where
    next a = Just $ Tuple a $ genericSucc a
```